# WPF DotNET Application will run in debug mode, but .EXE will not run

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, wpf-4.0, .net-4.0

I wrote a WPF application in C# using VS 2010. The application will run fine in debug mode using Visual Studio, but when I go to run the .EXE from the bin\release folder, nothing happens. I do not get any error messages from windows and there are no errors or warnings in VS. I have tried to build, rebuild and clean the solution (in every possible order) with no luck. My solution contains 2 projects, both of which use .NET 4.0 framework, and I have .NET 4.0 installed on my PC. I have tried on both XP and Win7 and still nothing.

I also just noticed that the output from Debug when I run the application in debug mode says: "Cannot find or open the PDB file" after each .Dll it loads.

I am compiling to the Release folder every time, but i did try changing it to the debug folder and clean/rebuild just to see if that would make a difference, and it didnt, so I changed it back, tried it again, and still nothing.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Interesting. Have you checked the Application Event Log to see if there's anything there?

Comment: Is the application running in your process list or did it start/end?

Comment: Also, have you gotten a non-error compilation when you change to Release mode? When you push F5 you are running in Debug mode, it'll compile to bin\Debug. Perhaps an old version is in bin\Release that doesn't actually do anything. Try changing the drop down to Release, then compiling with F6.

Comment: Also, when did you make any configuration changes in the Debug configuration for you project? At times one makes changes in Debug configuration which you need to do again in Release mode.

Comment: I was able to find just enough information in the Application Event Log to find an exception being thrown in the constructor of my main window. I am not sure why it wasnt caught in debug mode, but thanks for the tip Brian!

Comment: Another fun thing I found out that caused a similar error, but only on Windows XP: If you use a Windows Vista icon in the MainWindow Icon property in a WPF application, it will run on Windows 7, but not on XP.

Comment: Quite an old question but it might help other: For me running from the console (cmd.exe) worked for some reason.

Answer (score 10):

Here are a couple of ideas that come to mind

- If you are on a x64 machine, try changing the application from being AnyCPU to x86.  This the mode that applications default to in debug mode and it's possible an issue running in x64 is causing a problem in release builds
- Possible the Release binaries are out of date.  Delete the binaries from the Release folder, rebuild and run the newly generated runs
- Run the release build under the debugger in Visual Studio and see if it till crashes

Comment: This didn't happen to be my issue (this time), but still very useful info! Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I was experiencing the above issue too, however none of the other solutions worked for me.

My Application logs in Event Viewer listed event ids 1018 and 1022. This appeared to be bizarrely related to an ASP.NET 2.0 dll (bizarre; as this was a blank WPF project only).  The logs contained messages like this:

> Windows cannot open the 64-bit extensible counter DLL
>   ASP.NET_64_2.0.50727 in a 32-bit environment

In the end it turned out to be resolved when I **disabled my anti-virus**. I had read that this resolution worked for someone with McAfee; and it also worked for my environment, which has Avast.

Comment: Thanks you, we temporary added ours Wpf application to Avast exceptions on the computer and it worked. Now we have to find how not to be blocked from Avast.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you tried on a machine that doesn't have visual studio installed, and also none of the components you are using for development.

You have only one option: start the application with a debugger on the machine that causes problems and check for exceptions there. (use [WinDBG](https://web.archive.org/web/20110217084226/http://www.microsoft.com:80/whdc/devtools/debugging/default.mspx) for example - it's light and easy).

This looks like a problem with missing dependencies, but might be something else also.

The Debugging Labs should give you enough information on how to use windbg to find your problem:

- [.NET Debugging labs](https://web.archive.org/web/20151119050350/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/tess/archive/2008/02/04/net-debugging-demos-information-and-setup-instructions.aspx)

Also use this:

- [WinDBG Cheat Sheet](https://web.archive.org/web/20211023041127/http://windbg.info/doc/1-common-cmds.html#9_exceptions)

Comment: I did try using a debugger and after the app crashes, it just gives a message saying "No Source Availible".

Comment: But did you capture the exception message?

Answer (score 1):

(JaredPar) answer looks right (x64), but if not try right clicking on the EXE and running in admin mode for win 7.

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar issue.

Check out this setting on your App Pool entry:

- Go to Advanced Settings.
- Change 'Enable 32-bit Applications' to 'TRUE'.

This worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to go with a wild guess that:

- Either you have some odd corruption in your .NET Framework installation
- There is some debug/release-specific code using `#if DEBUG` or the such that is substantially different to cause issues.
- You have not compiled recently into Release yet (Try changing it to Release before compiling your latest code and make sure you get no errors).

Those are the only things I can think of off the top of my head.

Comment: I had to install .NET v4.0 on the XP machine I tried to run it on (that does not have VS on it) and still got nothing, and I dont think I have 2 corrupt versions of .NET Framework. I am compiling into release and get 0 errors and 0 warnings.

Answer (score 0):

I had run into a similar issue, I was missing a custom folder in the release mode I was referencing in the constructor. Adding the folder to the release fixed the problem.